# Getting the error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/nimbusds/oauth2/sdk/auth/ClientAuthentication while trying to read the mails from Graph API

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-mail

```
import com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.ClientCredentialFactory;
import com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.ClientCredentialParameters;
import com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.ConfidentialClientApplication;
import com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.IAuthenticationResult;
import com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.IClientCredential;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


public class DefaultEmailReaderGraph implements CreationService {
    DefaultEmailReaderGraph () {
    }
    public static final String CLIENT_ID = "800e0bd6-7848-4027-****-************";
    private static final  String AUTHORITY = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/1a6b5a68-46e7-****-****-************/";
    private static final  String CLIENT_SECRET = "******ZNodD*****ShmFB2yG46zi************";
    private static final  String TENANT_GUID="7370fc8f-4ead-****-****-************";
    private static final Set<String> SCOPES = Collections.singleton("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DefaultEmailReaderGraph.class);
    private static IAuthenticationResult getAccessToken() throws Exception {
    
        IAuthenticationResult result = null;
        try{
            IClientCredential credential = ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret(CLIENT_SECRET);
            ConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplication
                    .builder(CLIENT_ID, credential)
                    .authority(AUTHORITY)
                    .build();
            ClientCredentialParameters clientCredentialParameter = ClientCredentialParameters
                    .builder(SCOPES)
                    .build();
            CompletableFuture<IAuthenticationResult> future=app.acquireToken(clientCredentialParameter);
            result=future.get();
            final String  accessToken=result.accessToken();
            if(StringUtils.isBlank(accessToken)){
                LOG.error("Access Token :"+accessToken);
            }
            LOG.info("Token is :  "+app.acquireToken(clientCredentialParameter).join());
        }catch (Exception e){
            LOG.error("Exception in acquiring token: "+e.getMessage(),e);
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void createTicketFromEmail(Date lastEmailReadTime) throws Exception {
        IAuthenticationResult accessToke= getAccessToken();
    }
}
```

For the above code I am getting the below error in the console,

```
Caught throwable com/nimbusds/oauth2/sdk/auth/ClientAuthentication
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/nimbusds/oauth2/sdk/auth/ClientAuthentication
    at
```

Even thought I have added the jar for the `nimbusds` (`nimbus-jose-jwt-9.31.wso2v1`) to the lib folder.

I am trying to generate the access token from the above code so I can further use it to read the email from the Azure AD Mailbox

Comment: I am also getting this error - in a quite different scenario: trying to access `kusto` server from within `synapse`

Comment: Adding this repo to pom.xml fixed it for me https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.nimbusds/oauth2-oidc-sdk/11.9.1